# How to cheatedly update identity column?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, identity

In the table, there's an identity column incrementing by one each time we add a row (the lowest value is 1). Now, there's a new requirement - we need to implement soft deletion.

So, my idea was to basically multiply any softly deleted row by -1. That ensures the uniqueness and clearly draws a line between active and softly deleted item.

```
update Things set Id = -101
where Id = 101
```

Would you know, the stupid computer doesn't let me do that. The suggested work-around is to:

1. alternate the column
2. perform the update
3. alternate back the column

and to me it seems like a Q&D. However, the only alternative I can see is to add a new column carrying the deletion status.

I'm using EF to perform the work with the extra quirk that when I changed the value of the identity and stored it, the software was kind enough to think for me and actually **create** a new row (with incrementally set identity that was neither the original one, nor the negative of it).

How should I tackle this issue?

Comment: Have you tried your `UPDATE` with `SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Things ON`?

Comment: @stakx No, I haven't. Mostly because I didn't know about it. Now that I do, I still can't - it might have to do with me being on Sql Server. At any rate, we'll be doing that from Entity Framework and I'm not sure how to do the equivalent from that (or if it's possible at all).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would strongly discourage you from overloading your identity column with any additional meaning. Someone who will look at your database table for the first time has no way of knowing that a negative ID means "deleted".

Introducing a new column `Deleted BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0` does not have this disadvantage. It is self-explanatory. And it costs almost nothing: in the times of Big Data, an additional `BIT` column isn't going to fill your hard disk.

All of that being said, if you still want to do that, you could try to `SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Things ON` before you `UPDATE`. (I cannot currently verify whether that would work, though.)

Comment: The `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` wouldn't help, it must be done in the same session as the command and it doesn't apply to updates. Of course you're absolutely right that this is a hopeless appraoch. Breaking foreign keys has no even been mentioned yet.

Comment: @Gert: Thanks for your input. Concerning breaking foreign keys, that could be mitigated (somewhat) through `ON UPDATE CASCADE` rules. But I agree that it simply isn't a terribly good idea to modify a primary key.